# Skype invitation message

Tags: c#, skype4com

I want to invite a user sending a specific message, but I can't find where I can set invitation message.

This is a (simplified) sample of what I do:

```
skype.Client.Start(true, true);
var user = skype.SearchForUsers("the_name_i_am_searching_for")
    .Cast<User>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null)
    user.BuddyStatus = TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization;
```

With this code default invitation is sent.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291090/skype-how-to-get-started and find it in the code.

Comment: @YoelMacia: what should I take from that post? I know how to send messages to users and how to ask someone to be a skype friend; what I don't know is how modify the invitation message automatically sent then you do `user.BuddyStatus = TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use `Property` array instead of a simple assignment.
Change

```
user.BuddyStatus = TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization;
```

to

```
skype.Property["USER", "the_name_i_am_searching_for", "BUDDYSTATUS"] = 
    string.Format("{0} {1}", (int)TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization, 
                             "your welcome message")
```

I failed to find any official docs, but [this](http://pydoc.net/Python/Skype4Py/1.0.32.0/Skype4Py.user/) lib was very helpful. Notice `SetBuddyStatusPendingAuthorization` method

Comment: Thanks a lot Grin! Your sample was perfect!

Comment: Just a note: VS tells you is better using `skype.Property["USER", "the_name_i_am_searching_for", "BUDDYSTATUS"] = string.Format("{0} {1}", (int)TBuddyStatus.budPendingAuthorization, "your welcome message")`

Comment: @Marco I had to install R# to get this suggestion. Thanks for a note!

Answer (score 1):

The skype API offers a function `skype.SendMessage(<username>, <string>)` which I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, `SendMessage` is used to send a message to a user. Unfortunately it's not the message you send when you invite a user to become your friend...